# Is it possible to detach application windows out a VM?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I have a feeling the answer is no, but wanted to ask anyhow for confirmation.

Is there any VM software for windows that would allow the application windows to be detached from the VM, similar to what occurs in OS X virtualization software that is meant to run Windows on OSX.

I would like to run some applications from the VM and let them coexist on my regular windows (non-vm) desktop.

Comment: Which VM? Vmware has the unity Feature: http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C477788-7700-4030-8C4A-039C02AABB74.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) has a [seamless windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows) mode.
- VMware has a similar [Unity](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-8C477788-7700-4030-8C4A-039C02AABB74.html) mode.